# SetMaxThreads property of threadpool seems to has no impact, then why it is here?

Tags: .net, multithreading, msdn

Here is the simple program where I am testing threadpool.setmaxthreads property,   but it seems it has really no impact

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(2, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            new Thread(Go).Start();
//                Thread.Sleep(20000);
        } 
    }


    static void Go()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("From Thread#"+ Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId );
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Output

> From Thread#10
>
> From Thread#11
>
> From Thread#12
>
> From Thread#13
>
> From Thread#14

Comment: you are not using thread pool, instead, you start a new thread, not managed by the pool.

Comment: Before assuming that something is broken, consider that you may have misunderstood it. Especially with core features like the threadpool. You should at least read the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx) on the property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are not using threadpool, instead, you start new threads which are not managed by the threadpool. To start ThreadPool thread, you can use [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem(v=vs.110).aspx) method.
2. The parameters to [ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads(v=vs.110).aspx) method are invalid, so the method returns false, meaning the change is not successful.

From the [Remarks section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads(v=vs.110).aspx):

> You cannot set the maximum number of worker threads or I/O completion threads to a number smaller than the number of processors on the computer. To determine how many processors are present, retrieve the value of the Environment.ProcessorCount property. In addition, you cannot set the maximum number of worker threads or I/O completion threads to a number smaller than the corresponding minimum number of worker threads or I/O completion threads. To determine the minimum thread pool size, call the GetMinThreads method.

Here is the modified code for demonstration:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a; int b;
        ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out a, out b); //a=4, b=4 on my machine
        bool suc = ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(4, 4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(
                (o) =>
                {
                    Go();
                }));
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    static void Go()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("From Thread#" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine("End Thread#" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```